# reading geotags osx

Tags: macos, images, geotagging

How do I read the geotags of an image on OSX (or preferably online) for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you upload image to [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/). However, you have to first enable using EXIF GPS tags. You can do it [here](http://www.flickr.com/account/geo/exif/?from=privacy) (after creating an account). By default GPS tags are removed to protect your privacy.

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto supports geotags.  Just right click the image.